# Is this a design pattern? A class with multiple methods to create different objects from different input formats

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Is the following a known design pattern?

I have got **Class** with multiple methods to create different objects from different input formats.

```
E.g. Apologise for the pseudocode

// Definition 

CreatorClass() {
  func createCat(input -> array) -> Cat{
    Cat aCat = Cat()
    //...initialisation from array
    return aCat;
  }

  func createCat(input -> containerClass){
    Cat aCat = Cat()
    //...initialisation from containerClass
    return aCat;
  }

  func createCat(input -> dictionary){
    Cat aCat = Cat()
    //...initialisation from dictionary
    return aCat;
  }

  func createDog(input -> dictionary){
    Dog aDog = Dog()
    //...initialisation from dictionary 
    return aDog;
  }
}

// Usage
Creator aCreator = Creator()
Cat aCat = aCreator.createCat(array)
```

Comment: Looks like the factory pattern to me. I haven't read it fully though

Comment: It looks like a factory method, but this question shouldn't be here i guess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, it's called a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: Thanks! I have seen implementations of the factory design pattern,  using protocols/interfaces instead and implement the "creator methods" within the class.. was this a different design pattern? I am a little bit confused (e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: It's a variation of the same pattern.